# Is there an extremal epi which is not epi, although binary products exist?

Tags: category-theory

It is known, that in a category $\mathcal{A}$:

1. strong epis are epi, if $\mathcal{A}$ has binary products
2. extremal epis are epi, if $\mathcal{A}$ has equalizers
3. all strong epis are extremal
4. all extremal epis are strong, if $\mathcal{A}$ has pullbacks

(of course, here I do not require epicness in the definition of strong or extremal epis)

Can it be that $\mathcal{A}$ has binary products and an extremal epi which is *not* epi? (bearing in mind that in this case $\mathcal{A}$ cannot have all pullbacks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the category of sets that are not singletons? Monomorphisms, epimorphisms and binary products are easily seen to be the same as in the category of all sets, but the map $f:\{x,y\}\to\{a,b\}$ with $f(x)=a=f(y)$ is extremal "epi".

Comment: This seems to work. Nice! - I am fond of saying "extremaly epi", although I don't think this is standard ;)